# Why <a href> is not allowed as child of <figure>

Tags: html, validation, syntax-error

Here is a bit of code that w3.org doesn't validate:

```
<figure class="image">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <figcaption>
        <small>Cabinet Artwork</small>
        <br>
        Pretty in Pink in Mt Albert
    </figcaption>
    <a href="#" class="more"></a>
</figure>
```

The validator throws an error, stating that "Element a not allowed as child of element figure in this context". However, `<figure>` is a block level element and a parent of a child `<a href>`, and should be allowed here. Why is it a validation error then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[The spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) content model for `<figure>` is:

> Either: One `figcaption` element followed by flow content.
>   Or: Flow content followed by one `figcaption` element.
>   Or: Flow content.

You have a combination of rule 1 and 2 (one `figcaption` preceded *and* followed by flow content), which is not allowed.

In other words, `<figcaption>` must be either the first or the last element inside `<figure>`. It can't be in the middle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Juhana! You are awesome!